# execute permission problem with php file

Tags: permissions, php

When I create a `php` file it have not permission execute so I can't run php file.

I need to set permissions of that file. I want that all created php files have execute permission.

new creation file type is

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 sohel sohel     0 Apr 11 15:43 test.php
```

Comment: sorry .Not satisfied with this answer.I want execution permission when i create that file.see my last line.But your answer help me to use native apache server.so i vote it up.Thanks

Comment: How do you create `test.php`? Could you do `chmod a+x test.php` after creating the file? See `man chmod`, `man 2 chmod` and `info coreutils 'chmod invocation'`

Comment: using sublime-text Ctrl+n and save with ctrl+shift+s .yes i am doing a+x after creating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add execution permission on php files, install `php5-cli`:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

And now to run your php file, just type:

```
php test.php
```

Alternatively to really make it executable, add the php [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29):

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php 
Print "Hello, World!";
?>
```

And add the execution permission on your file:

```
chmod +x ./test.php
```

Comment: i am using lampp server then

Comment: I've updated my answer